# What looks like a counting glitch in EE's reputation scores for December 2020

Tags: bug, reputation, users-page

The [Electrical Engineering users page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users) is showing this in the monthly view for December 2020: -

[image: users page with wrong reputation]

The reputation for the top user is 3429 for example.

This is the daily reputation breakdown on [the top user's profile page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/35530/spehro-pefhany?tab=reputation) for December 2020: -

[image: Actual December reputation for top user]

Summing the reputation up gives: 50+100+85+30+95+10+65+20+180+155=790

This is **much lower** than what is shown in the [Electrical Engineering users monthly page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users) shown earlier. It's the same for other users as well. It looks like the points are rolled-over from somewhere else or just somehow miscalculated.

The top two or three user scores appear to be showing this problem. This problem may be more far-reaching than just a few at the top.

I originally emailed stack overflow support but they told me to **raise this bug here**: -

[image]

Comment: This has been [reported on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403382/7296893) as well, and as Martijn noted, apparently is a common regression (time to write a test probably)

Comment: OK, the problem appears to have been fixed overnight (UK). Thank you.